# What kinds of mistakes does transpose fix?

Tags: text-editing

The only times I've ever found a use for transpose-words or transpose-chars is when I accidentally hit one of them unintentionally, in which case a backward-word followed by transpose-words again would undo the problem.

It seems like the use case is something along the lines of accidentally typing `food dog` while meaning to type `dog food`, in which case transposition is helpful. For characters, I've always found backspace twice + retyping the two characters just as fast and less error-prone.

However, I have never, ever had this "word dyslexia" problem in my history of using Emacs. Given the relatively "important" key bindings that `transpose` commands get, it seems like I may be missing an important use case. Am I?

Comment: When revising text is often useful to be able to swap words around easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While `transpose-chars` is useful for typos in any kind of buffer, I suspect `transpose-words` is not particularly useful when writing prose but might be useful in programming or dealing with other kinds of text.

Note that `transpose-words` preserves punctuation. For example (with | indicating point):

- Starting with `[1][2][|3]`, use `M-t` to get: `[1][3][2|]`
- Starting with `foo += |bar`, use `M-t` to get: `bar += foo|`
- Starting with `one|, two, three, four,`, use `M-3 M-t` to get `two, three, four, one|,`

The last example uses a prefix argument to jump a word forward 3 places.

Also useful is the 0 prefix argument (`M-0 M-t`) to exchange the word at point with the word at mark. This can be a faster way to swap a couple words at arbitrary locations then using kill/yank. For example, type:

```
John, Ringo, George, and Paul|
```

That looks wrong, so use this sequence to fix it:

```
C-r rin    ; jump back to Ringo, leaving mark where you started
RET        ; quit the search
M-0 M-t    ; swap word at point (Ringo) with word at mark (Paul)
```

And voilà:

```
John, Paul, George, and Ringo|
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what other have said:

1. `transpose-sexps` (**`C-M-t`**) is *very handy*. I use it quite often in Emacs-Lisp mode.
2. Think keyboard macros. Any command such as `transpose-words` can be useful from a macro or from Lisp code. IOW, you might not find it useful to use it only once, as a one-off, but you might find it useful if you have to carry out hundreds of similar transpositions as part of a text or code transformation.

Answer (score 1):

I use `transpose-chars` when fixing bad TeX code (I am an editor for mathematical publications). Authors will often include, for instance, a comma inside math, eg:

```
So we have $x=y,$ which implies that...
```

For technical reasons we don't want the comma inside the dollar signs, so rather than killing the two characters and retyping them I place point on the second $ and use `transpose-chars`. For letters it might not make much difference but it's easier to hit `C-t` than to type `$,`.

Admittedly this is a rather specialized use case.